# Why is it generating an error of index out of range for 1?

Tags: python, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception, outofrangeexception

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    text1 = text.replace("-", "")
    text2 = text1.replace("_", "")
    text4 = text2[1]
    if text2.istitle == True :
        return text2
    elif text2[1].islower():
        text3 = text2[2:]
        return text2 + text3.title()
```

I wrote the above code for camel-casing. But in line 4 , it is showing the following error. "1" can't be out of range
[image]

Comment: Any index could be out of range. For example, what should `print(my_str[0])` produce when `my_str = ""`?

Comment: What argument are you passing?

Answer (score 1):

1. First character in a string has index 0, not 1. This is a widely used convention: almost in all programming languages, including python.
2. Empty string doesn't have even first character. So `text[1]` and `text[0]` will throw. Before extracting characters from your string, check it for emptiness: `if not text: return text` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the above error is because you are passing in an empty string of length=0, i.e. the index at text2[1] does not exist.

So, before manipulating your string add check to see if it is a string.

Comment: but it isn't an empty string

Comment: @AayanAgarwal This is the best guess, based on your screenshot, which says "An empty string was provided". If you really don't want to use an empty string, please edit your question and specify which argument you are passing.